# Angular input auto size not working with typeahead

Tags: angular6, typeahead

I'm working with ng-typeahead. I'm using ngx-input-autosize on my input field. When i write in my input field it is working fine. But when I'm using ng-typeahead, then ngx-input-autosize not resizing.
[image]